# Connecting WD World Book to my new laptop using downloaded win 7 driver

Tags: windows-7, backup, external-hard-drive

I have just been reading through and seeing that you can connect using a USB straight to your laptop.  This would be great is I actually had the cable! My problem is I have a lovely new laptop with windows 7 - I had to buy this as my old laptop isnt working anymore and I have just ordered an external sata enclosure to see whether I can get any inormation of the old drive and put onto my new laptop, so at least I don't lose any work.  This in itself will probably present problems as my old OS was Windows XP!  I will deal with that when i get to it!!  My problem at present is that I have a World Book and I wish to connect and configure it to my new laptop but again I need to download drivers for Windows 7, which I believe I have done, but now I can't seem to work out just what to do next to help these 2 devices to recognize each other and configure.  If anyone has any answers or could talk me through it I would be really grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you installed the drivers correctly. The website says that it's compatable with windows 7. There's no reason it shouldn't work without them unless it's a hardware problem.